# eclipse C++ code autocompletion (completion)

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

The problem is when I have created variable and after that I write first letter to use it, but I don`t see code completion.How can I solve it?[like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX2ig.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked Windows -> Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced and see which proposals are checked off? For the most part that is the place that controls the autocomplete functionality in Eclipse. You may also try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and see if a window opens asking if you want to turn Autocomplete on.

Comment: Thank,you bro) But all flags are checked and I can  see autocomplete box only when push ctrl+space but not automaticaly. Can I somehow fix It?

Comment: So pressing Ctrl+Space is the only way to get autocomplete to come up, but it doesn't prompt you to turn it on? And you said all of the boxes are checked under Windows -> Preferences -> C++ -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced?  Usually the one that needs to be turned on is Parsing-Based Proposals. Also, are you using a Standard or Managed Make project? Do you have your include paths set up?

Comment: 1.Standart project   2.About what you say(include paths)?